# Bayesian Classifier Combination indexing issue using PYMC3/Theano

Tags: bayesian, pymc3

I have been trying to work out how to define a model for Bayesian Classifier Combination according to [Kim, Ghahramani (2012)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v22/kim12/kim12.pdf) in PYMC3 (see directed graphical model below (Figure 1 in the paper))

[Directed Graphical Model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72jyN.png)

The idea is that you have an exponential prior over parameters alpha_k for each k classifiers confusion matrix pi_k, which are sampled from Dirichlet.

Similarly, we have a Dirichlet prior for the generated target t_i values generated from Multinomial. Then, conditioning on the value of the t_i, we sample values for classifier outputs c_i from Multinomial.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out how to index confusion matrices pi, given the value of the target t. (I have used Categorical distribution instead of Multinomial). Variable c_train is a list of length k=4 numpy arrays of shape (I=100,) corresponding to the classification from the classifiers.

```
I = 100 # number of instances
J = 3 # number of classes 
K = 4 # number of classifiers
nu_vec = np.array([1. for _ in range(J)], dtype=np.float32)
lambda_mat = np.array([[.01, .02, .03], [.04, .05, .06], [.07, .08, .09]], dtype=np.float32)

with pm.Model() as model:

        p_vec = pm.Dirichlet(name='p_vec', a=nu_vec)

        t = pm.Categorical(name='t', p=p_vec, shape=I)

        alpha = [pm.Exponential('alpha_{}'.format(k), lam=lambda_mat, shape=(J, J)) for k in range(K)]

        pi = [[pm.Dirichlet('pi_j{}k{}'.format(j, k), alpha[k][j], shape=(3)) for j in range(J)] for k in range(K)]

        c = [[] for k in range(K)]

        for i in range(I):

            for k in range(K):

                c[k].append(pm.Categorical('c_k{}i{}', p=pi[k][t[i]], observed=c_train[k][t[i]]))
```

The code above, returns a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not FreeRV. Would very much appreciate any suggestions or help!